# Change time zone in as.POSIXct

Tags: r

I want to change a date-time string into POSIXct with the '+00' in behind indicating the time zone.

This is what I did

```
as.POSIXct("2018-2-12-1230", format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")
>"2018-02-12 12:30:00 CST"
```

However instead of `"2018-02-12 12:30:00 CST"`, I would like `"2018-02-12 12:30:00 +08"` as output. How can I do that in `as.POSIXct`?

Comment: how about as.POSIXct("2018-2-12-1230", format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M", tz="Etc/GMT-8")?

Comment: *"as output"*: you cannot have anything non-standard in the output while preserving the `POSIXt` class of the object. My recommendation: *accept* that the default R output for numeric-like `POSIXt` class objects is not ideal, and when you *need* it to be in a specific format (e.g., in a report), then convert it to a string using `gsub("00$', "", format(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"))`. The point of this is that as long as you want to be able to treat it like a timestamp (add/subtract, difference, etc), then you need to tolerate how R displays it on the console.